# Is any errno a valid POSIX return value for read()?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Is it POSIX, to return in a device driver read function, any of the available errno value listed in errno.h or should I just used those listed in the read linux man page ?

edit:

I'm writting a device driver in which the user has to set some parameter using an ioctl cmd before calling the read function. So I'm looking for the right errno value to return, if the user try to call the read function before setting those parameters. EPERM "Operation not permitted" seems rigth but because it's not listed in the read linux man page, I'm wondering if this a correct implementation.

Comment: I guess it'd be better if you explain what you are doing, otherwise looks like not a real question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Linux manpages are generally pretty good, but they are not authoritative.  For a question like this, you need to go to the official standards.  You should only return one of the error codes listed in the [POSIX.1-2008 specification for `read`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html) (scroll down to where it says ERRORS).  If you return some other code, application software will not be prepared to handle it and may crash.

Be aware that many of those codes may *only* be returned under the conditions described for them.  For instance, your device driver has no business returning `EBADF`, `EISDIR`, `EOVERFLOW`, `ESPIPE`, or anything with the word "socket" in its description, because all the circumstances where those are the appropriate failure codes are dealt with before control reaches you.  This is *probably* also the case for `EINTR` but I'm not sure.

You also should know that Linux doesn't implement some of the optional features of POSIX.1-2008 (most importantly here, pretend everything marked OB_XSR isn't there at all) and that some of the distinctions made by the standard are obsolescent (such as `ENOMEM` versus `ENOBUFS`).

Putting it all together, unless your device driver is very unusual, I expect you should only need `EIO`, `EAGAIN`, `ENOMEM`, and *maybe* `ENXIO` (if the `EIO`/`ENXIO` distinction is meaningful for your hardware).

Comment: OK, in my case ENXIO looks better "A request was outside the capabilities of the device."

Comment: Yeah, or - despite its not being on the list - `EINVAL`, which is a generic "what you just tried to do doesn't make any sense" code that application software generally *is* prepared to cope with.  Definitely do not use `EPERM`; that is reserved for privilege checks, which it is not a device driver's job to enforce, and anyway they happen in `open`, not `read`.

Comment: [POSIX says that](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_03) *Implementations... may generate additional errors unless explicitly disallowed for a particular function.*, and `read()` does not explicitly disallow this.  Portable programs should be written to expect that the POSIX list of errors is not exhaustive.

Comment: @caf "Be conservative in what you send" applies; the *device driver* author is best advised to stick to the documented list, even though the *application* author should be prepared to cope with more variety.

Answer (score 2):

POSIX requires that the listed error codes be used to report the corresponding error condition.  However it also allows other error codes to be used for errors that are not listed.

The [text](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_03) from POSIX.1-2008 Volume 2: System Interfaces, section 2.3 Error Numbers:

> Implementations may support additional errors not included in this
>   list, may generate errors included in this list under circumstances
>   other than those described here, or may contain extensions or
>   limitations that prevent some errors from occurring.
>
> The ERRORS section on each reference page specifies which error
>   conditions shall be detected by all implementations ("shall fail")
>   and which may be optionally detected by an implementation ("may
>   fail"). If no error condition is detected, the action requested shall
>   be successful.
>
> Implementations may generate error numbers listed here under
>   circumstances other than those described, if and only if all those
>   error conditions can always be treated identically to the error
>   conditions as described in this volume of POSIX.1-2008.
>   Implementations shall not generate a different error number from one
>   required by this volume of POSIX.1-2008 for an error condition
>   described in this volume of POSIX.1-2008, but may generate additional
>   errors unless explicitly disallowed for a particular function.